# Reading animation into BMesh and output to png sequence not working - animation looks weird

Tags: python, animation, scripting, bmesh

I am new to Blender scripting, and am trying to animate a flag blowing in the wind, read the vertex positions etc. per frame into memory using `BMesh`, write the `BMesh` object back into the mesh, and save the resulting animation to png files on the disk. This is so I can modify the vertex positions/velocities mid-animation in future.

I have done the following:

1. Make a flag using a plane and some pinned vertices using a `make_new_flag()` method, and set up Wind etc.
2. (Code below) Simulate the animated frames and save them to a list of `BMesh` objects, one per frame of the animation:

```py
simulation_frames = []
for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end, scene.frame_step):
    print("Setting frame to: ", f)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
    # define new bmesh object:
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282889/to-mesh-in-blender-3
    dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    obj = original_plane.evaluated_get(dg)
    mesh = obj.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=dg)
    # read the evaluated mesh data into the bmesh   object:
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)
    simulation_frames.append(bm)
render_bmesh_to_png(simulation_frames)
```

3. Read back from the list of BMesh objects and save the animated frames to disk as PNG file:

```py
def render_bmesh_to_png(meshes: list[BMesh]):
    num_images_to_render = len(mixed_mesh)
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

    for frame_number in range(num_images_to_render):
        print("Rendering frame ", frame_number, " of ", num_images_to_render)
       
        # Reset the plane object
        plane_name = make_new_flag()
        plane = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(plane_name)

        # Update not happening properly here?
        meshes[frame_number].to_mesh(plane.data)
        plane.data.update()

        # TODO Removing these lines results in a static mesh with no animation
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")

        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

However, I am getting weird animation, as shown in frames 2 and 3 of the output:

[image: weird flag frame 2]

[image: weird flag frame 3]

I have searched and not found anything useful unfortunately.

Any help in pointing out issues in the code would be appreciated!

Comment: is a python solution necessary for you? because it can be done totally without python...

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately, I would like to try some stuff that involves mesh manipulation for large scenes several times, and it would seem very difficult to do without any scripting...

Comment: `BMesh` is not defined in your code. please provide a minimally "working" script.